# How to return part of folder name in C#

Tags: c#, regex, directory

Hi I have an instance where I am trying to return part of a folder name. My application is writtern in c#

My folder name returns this "Fri 11.4.97"

I only want to return the "11.4.97" part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string folderName = "Fri 11.4.97"
string[] parts = folderName.Split(' ');
string lastPart = parts[parts.Length - 1];
```

Case in point: For such a simple case, a Regex might not be needed; and the above code might be more readable.

Comment: Thanks heap, This method is great because I did not mention that some the dates might be separated by a period(.), other times by a dash(-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how well specified the input format is. If the file specification is always `XXX blah blah blah` where `XXX` is the bit you don't need (three characters for the day plus a space), you can just use a simple [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx):

```
String dateBit = fspec.Substring (4);
```

Only if the file specification wasn't very "solid" would I consider using a regular expression. By that, I mean examples such as having the *full* day `Friday`, or *two* spaces between the day and date. If you're always going to have a three-character date and single-character separator, the substring is probably the more natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

`\d+\.\d+\.\d+` will match three numeric fields, each separated by a period, without concern for the rest of the input.